# How to feed client-side AJAX script with an ASP.NET server side *DYNAMIC* .json and .xml file?

Tags: asp.net, xml, ajax, json, dynamic

As I learned so far, client-side AJAX script can read a **static** .json or .xml file from server e.g. http://www.mydomain.com/all_cities.xml.

But I need to generate a .json or .xml file **dynamically** according to the user input at client-side. e.g. imagine that the user selects a state from DropDownList1 and AJAX should fill DropDownList2 with that state's cities; while I don't like to send all cities and then filtering desired cities in client-side!

So, I would like to know how ASP.NET can handle this e.g. when it sees "http://www.mydomain.com/cities.json?state=9" then it should response with a dynamically created json file named cities.json which contains the cities which are in state #9?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET WebForms or MVC?

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET WebForms. Why it makes difference?!

Comment: Well that will make difference in my response... since there are number of ways to achieve this, i just wanted to make scope a bit narrow...

Comment: Are you using AjaxToolKit Update Panel or jQuery?

Comment: not AjaxToolKit nor jQuery. I'm using JavaScript and XMLHttpRequest activex! I prefer doing things from scratch to have more control on them ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this - basically, the simplest is to have any standard web page (be it forms, an MVC controller/action/etc...) that acts like any normal webpage would with user input but instead of returning html, it returns XML. (By returns XML, I mean make the contents of the page solely XML and add the appropriate headers)

Your question is too broad to give more details - but simply put, it's easily done and the client (JavaScript in this case) can't usually tell the difference.

Comment: Did you mean writing e.g. an XML download code by HTTP headers and content type?

Comment: I mean have _some_ form of server code which returns the dynamic XML and then call that from JS - If you're using forms, you'd have an a page which is called by your JS. in the code behind, have code which prepares your XML and returns is (probably via `response.write()`) to the user. In short, just return valid xml and a content-type of `text/xml`

Comment: Have a look here http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092403-1.aspx for an example of what I mean. In case you prefer VB, tyhere's a converter here: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: Thanks a tone! the "Emitting XML Content to the Browser Window Directly" section of http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092403-1.aspx is exactly what I was looking for! thanks again @Basic

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a WCF service, you could have a WebGet that accepts the state as a parameter and returns the cities for that state:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "cities/{state}")]
public List<string> GetCities(string state)
{
    List<string> citiesFromState;
    // Build up a List of cities based on the state sent
    return citiesFromState;
}
```

In the web.config for your application, set `automaticFormatSelectionEnabled` to true so that WCF will look at the 'Accept' header of the HTTP request to determine what format to send the response in (e.g. xml or json):

```
<behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
    <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" helpEnabled="true"/>
</behavior>
```

This allows WCF to handle the serialization for you.  Otherwise, you could do the serialization manually in the `WebGet`.

Comment: Is there any simpler way avoiding WCF? I don't like to reach WCF complicated staffs

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to achieve this is

On Client Side:  use jQuery and call a method/service to return JSON. Something like

```
function CallService() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", //HTTP verb
        url: serviceUrl,
        data: "{}", //Data sent to server
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // content type sent to server
        dataType: "json", //Expected data format from server e.g. json, xml etc.
        success: OnSuccess
    });
}

function OnSuccess(data) {
    var options = $(".InputDropDown"); //.InputDropDown is class assigned to dropdown
    //don't forget error handling! 
    $.each(data, function (index) {
        var item = data[index];
        options.append($("<option />").val(item.Id).text(item.Name));
    });
}
```

this method will be called on first drop down change

On Server Side: use either Web Service (or WCF) method or Page Methods (in your web app) that return JSON.

```
    [WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Countries")]
    List<Country> GetCountries();
```

If you are new to jQuery etc. I would strongly recommend you to go through this.

An example of **alternative approach (without WCF)** of using PageMethod and plain JavaScript can be found at [LINK-1](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article454-using-pagemethods-and-json-in-aspnet-ajax.aspx) and [LINK-2](http://setiabud.blogspot.com/2008/11/using-pagemethods-json-to-provide-auto.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read in static content, you'll only be able to use .XML by default since .JSON is not a default MIME-TYPE supported by IIS.  Here is an example on how to read static a static XML file into your page using the ajax() method of jQuery.

Static File "cities.xml".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<cities>
    <city>City A</city>
    <city>City B</city>
    <city>City C</city>
</cities>
```

jQuery Code to read Static XML and parse into a JavaScript array.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'cities.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function (xml)
    {
        var cities = [];

        $(xml).find('city').each(function ()
        {
            cities[cities.length] = $(this).text();
        });

        // Do something with your array of values here.
    }
});
```

Comment: As I cited, I want to generate cities.xml at server side on the fly then feed it to AJAX XMLHttpRequest at client side when this xml file is requested by state code as parameter.